# Can't find values from my friendly url rules (HTACCESS)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my wampserver reach my querystring vars under friendly urls (htaccess changes).

All I can get is a notice telling me that they don't exist...

What is wrong?

My rewrite_modulo is ON. By default, wampserver calls products.php if I type "http://localhost/product".

But I can't access my url vars!

My folder is "project" (inside www dir)

-> www/project

Here is what I get:

My HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /project/
  RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

And my "products.php" is like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

?>
```

But when I run this page (http://localhost/products/myID/myName) I get this notices:

> - Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\project\products.php on line 5
> - Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\project\products.php on line 6

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `NC` flag, exactly, but perhaps you should review the [httpd mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) to understand what those flags actually do. For example, [specifically what the L flag does in .htaccess directory block](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) might be a good start.

Comment: I used NC to ignore case sensitive..

Answer (score 0):

Add the QSA (query string append) flag to your rule, like:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Important: no spaces between the comma-delimited flags.

Comment: Still getting the notices =(

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn `MultiViews` option off:

```
Options -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /products.php?id=$2&name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: What URL are you using for testing: `http://localhost/products/myID/myName` OR `http://localhost/projects/products/myID/myName`? Also check with my updated rule.